# Clauses after prepositions

Tags: prepositions, objects

Many sources say to use noun phrases, nouns, or objective pronouns as objects of preposition. As per that, "Like I said" should be corrected to "As I said."  At the same time, we have sources which agree with using noun clauses and gerunds as objects of prepositions. The following are valid sentences which agree with noun clauses as objects of preposition.

Examples: The extra doughnuts are free to **whoever wants them.**

She is saving her trump card for **when she needs it most.**

I cannot work with **people who aren't interested in teamwork.**

Please clarify the confusion.

Comment: ["It is said to use" would mean "some object or animal is said to use"]

Comment: I don't understand the question. Your three examples are all perfectly natural. There are still plenty of pedants ready to complain about people mixing up ***as*** and ***like***, but almost all native speakers *sometimes* use those words in ways that others might complain about. And I don't see how that ***like / as*** distinction relates to the rest of the question text.

Comment: I have read from many sources that finite clauses should not be used after prepositions. "As I said" is correct compared to "like I said." We met during my stay in Paris VS We met when/while I was staying in Paris. (preposition with the phrase, conjunction with the clause). If that information is correct then is it not in conflict with the examples in bold- which are correct?

Comment: Everyone uses "like I said" to mean "as I said". Where is a finite clause used after a preposition??

Comment: @brp7 Prepositions can certainly take clauses as complement. Both "like I said" and "as I said" are preposition phrases headed by the preps "like" and "as" with the subordinate clause "I said" as complement. However, none of your examples have a clause as complement of a preposition: "whoever wants them" and "people who aren't interested in teamwork" are noun phrases, and "when she needs it most" is a preposition phrase.

Comment: @BillJ I'm afraid I have to disagree. They are finite clauses. Likewise, 'I said' (have subject +simple past verb)  is a finite clause. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/clauses-finite-and-non-finite . All the bold letters in the examples are finite clauses. Noun phrase after preposition: The comic book is about a rich guy dressed like a bat. (verbal- past participle, not a finite)
Noun phrase after preposition: He is searching for a girl who can talk to ghosts. (verbal-not a finite)                                        continued.

Comment: Noun clause after prep: The extra doughnuts are free to whoever wants them. (wants- simple present- shows tense - so finite)
Noun clause after prep: She is saving her trump card for when she needs it most. (shows tense- so finite) https://www.thesaurus.com/e/grammar/object-of-preposition/

Comment: "Whoever wants them" is an NP in a fused relative construction, where the meaning is (roughly) "any person who wants them". In "when she needs it most", "when" is a preposition in a relative construction, where the meaning is "On the occasion when she needs it most". And "people who aren't interested in teamwork" is a noun phrase headed by the noun "people", which is modified by the relative clause "who aren't interested in teamwork" Now do you see?

Comment: I already told you that "I said" is a subordinate clause. But the examples in bold are not clauses, as I explained to you above. Further, there is no such thing as a 'noun clause', The classification of finite subordinate clauses is based on their internal form rather than spurious analogies with the parts of speech.

Comment: I don't have any doubt as to whether they are clauses.

Comment: Do you have any source that says "When' is a preposition - as you said?

Comment: [CGEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cambridge_Grammar_of_the_English_Language) defines "preposition" in an expansive way that includes "when". CGEL makes arguments to justify this decision, but it is a departure from tradition: their definition of "preposition" is definitely not the most common one, and "when" is more commonly considered an adverb.

Comment: @nschneid Even if "when" were an adverb, "when she needs it most" would still not be a clause but an AdvP, contrary to what the OP believes.

Comment: Agreed, it's a free/fused relative construction.

Comment: In the traditional view (as in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/when)), *when* is a conjunction when followed by a clause. This doesn't match modern thinking about syntax, but lexicographers are not grammarians and that's what dictionary people say.

Comment: I'm surprised MW says that even for the relative construction usage (their conjunction sense 4). [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/when) has relative examples as adverb senses. In general, some usages are borderline between relative and non-relative interpretations. I ended up developing [these criteria](https://universaldependencies.org/en/dep/acl-relcl.html#testing-whether-wh-adverb-is-a-relativizer) for a corpus project.

Answer (score 2):

A clear example of a finite clause as complement of a preposition is:

- I am confused **about** whether I should say it this way.

Some grammatical descriptions might call "about" used in this way a *subordinating conjunction* rather than a preposition. This is based on a tradition in English grammar that is now controversial; many linguists would say this "about" is a preposition just like it would be in "I am confused about the problem".

So, it depends on your definition of "preposition". But many *words* that occur as prepositions with a noun phrase may also occur in the same meaning with a clause.